# Passing list of objects to create with arguments to constructor or method

Tags: c#, constructor, activator

Basically what I'm trying to do is to make a class that can mass-create objects using

```
Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, params object[] args)
```

I will need to pass all the object blueprints to a constructor of a class called ObjectMap. It will need to be pairs of a type and the arguments. It can also be a method in another class instead of a constructor if that allows for a solution.

sort of like

```
new ObjectMap([Type, somevalue, somevalue, somevalue], [Type, somevalue], [Type] ...)
```

or

```
Resources.AddObjectMap([Type, somevalue, somevalue, somevalue], [Type, somevalue], [Type] ...)
```

I have no idea how to make it so that you can pass a variable amount of pairs with a variable amount of arguments (even 0). Heck I'm even having a hard time trying to explain the issue. Ask me anything that's unclear to you =S

Gr.Viller

Comment: Its pretty unclear... but generally you have to always use the same number of arguments in a constructor even if some can be null

Comment: It is possible for me to turn it into a method in another class, which will just set the values in the new ObjectMap object. Will that allow for a solution?

Comment: I think so but I believe the below solution is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest you encapsulate the "type and args" into a specific type... then you can use a `params` array of that. For example:

```
// TODO: Find a better name :)
public class TypeBlueprint
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public List<object> Arguments { get; set; }

    public TypeBlueprint()
    {
        this.Arguments = new List<object>();
    }

    public TypeBlueprint(Type type, params object[] arguments)
    {
        this.Type = type;
        this.Arguments = arguments.ToList();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
public ObjectMap(params TypeBlueprint[] blueprints)
```

And call it with:

```
var map = new ObjectMap(new TypeBlueprint(typeof(Foo), "x", "y", "z"),
                        new TypeBlueprint { Type = typeof(Bar),
                                            Arguments = { 1, 2, 3 } });
```

That demonstrates using both constructor parameters and object initializers to specify the type and arguments. Use whichever is best for you.

Comment: That's exactly what I looked for and didn't think about. Thanks a bunch! =)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are asking for... (I think the real answer yo our question is the use of `params` in the function parameter list)

Implementation:

```
public class ObjectMap
{
    public object[] ActivatedObjects { get; private set; }

    public ObjectMap(params object[][] itemsToMap)
    {
        ActivatedObjects = itemsToMap.Select(ActivateItem).ToArray();
    }

    private object ActivateItem(object[] itemToActivate)
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance((Type)itemToActivate[0], itemToActivate.Skip(1).ToArray());
    }
}
```

Basic unit test:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest3
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var map = new ObjectMap(new object[] {typeof(Class1)},
                  new object[] {typeof(Class2), "Arg One", 2});

        Assert.AreEqual(2, map.ActivatedObjects.Length);
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(map.ActivatedObjects[0], typeof(Class1));
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(map.ActivatedObjects[1], typeof(Class2));
    }
}

public class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    public Class2(string arg1, int arg2)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: I support Jon Skeet's suggestion to make the parameters a class, but since your question had arrays in it, I stuck with arrays. Using untyped arrays is certainly more error prone, and I know I didn't add any error handling. I was simply providing an implementation that created instances based on arrays.